# How to wake up the android app at specific time?

Tags: android

I want to wake up my whole android app daily at 9 am . I tried using alarm manager of android.
But it calls pending intent. But in my case not pending intent , i want to wake full app.
Following is my code . As i am beginner in android development any help is greatly appreciated .

```
public void SetAlarm() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 09);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
    alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
  }
```

And in MainActivity class :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  String ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Android; Tablet; rv:20.0) Gecko/20.0 Firefox/20.0";
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.setBackgroundColor(0);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    myWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(ua);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());
    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    SetAlarm();
  }
}
```

But at 9 am it is not waking my app up . Any mistakes ??

Comment: Make sure you have the wake device permission in your manifest, `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />`

Comment: I have added this permission

Comment: @SSS please see my answer and it will work 100%

Answer (score 1):

introduce(`BroadcastReceiver`) one more step to open your full app.

`AlarmManager` -> `broadcastReceiver` -> Your Apps splash/launcher page

Thats it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are opening an activity you should be using `PendingIntent.getActivity` rather than `PendingIntent.getBroadcast`

Answer (score 1):

As you want to set daily instead of `alarmMgr.set` use `alarmMgr.setReapting` alarm.

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(con, YourAppReciever.class);
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(con, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Create a receiver and listen for this broadcast.

```
public class YourAppReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, MainActivity.class));
    }

}
```

Comment: The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type yourAppReciever. I am getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

Follow below instruction.

**1. MainActivity.java**

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, myIntent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
            long interval = 60 * 1000; //
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
```

**Step 2:**
 Boradcast Receiver for start Your Activity.

**MyReceiver.java**

```
 public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent myIntent =new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(myIntent);
        System.out.println("Receiver Call");
    }


}
```

**Step 3:**
Put into your `manifest.xml`

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver"/>
```

Change interval valuse as per your requirement **if require 24 hours then interval=24*60*60*1000.**

This is General solution for stackoverflow user pleas modify as per your requirement.

It will work perfect.Happy coding.

Comment: I tried your code . Once i install it should start automatically right? But it is not waking up

Comment: Can u tel me how to set the time after(5 minutes from now) 5 minutes?? So that i can check whether it is waking up or not??

Comment: According to your code it will start now and repeat for every second correct??

Comment: So each time we run this code time will change right?? Can u pls explain?? I am not getting it

Comment: for 5 minute set interval=5*60*60*1000

Comment: No .. it is repeating faster.. What do u mean by calendar.add(Calendar.Second,10)??

Comment: How to write hour of day?? Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 50);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);It will set for 10.50 am right??